# GPS location shortened in Android 6

Tags: android, gps

I have developed software which provides me with GPS long. and lat. positions. Before Android 6 I received GPS positions with 14 digits after the decimal point. After upgrading the software to Android 6 (basically adding the relevant permissions) the same code now returns me GPS positions with only 7 digits after the decimal point. The code i am using both before and under Android 6 is: locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 3000, 10, this);
Can someone explain this, and if I've missed something, inform me? Other than the above the software performs exactly as designed. (Both pre- and post android 6 Network return 7 decimal digits).

Comment: Since 5 significant digits takes you to the limits of GPS accuracy (~1m), what does it matter whether the nature of floating-point precision give you the appearance of 7 or 14?

Comment: It matters because I want to know why I am not getting what i had pre- Android 6. I don't believe that android decided to shorten the number of digits, so I am asking if there is a new way of obtaining  the data as before. The software is intended to assist location of lost handicapped persons, and a few meters difference can mean a wrong turning or entrance.

Comment: How do you determine this? The coordinates are given as doubles which has ~15 digits of accuracy in older and newer Android versions so there's no real reason for it to suddenly remove digits and considering the values rarely would hit perfectly a certain number of digits I'd assume presentation is showing only a certain amount. But as said the GPS system can't handle that many decimals anyway

Comment: My question is simple: I had 14 decimal digits and now I don't. Let me amplify: I currently develop on a Galaxy 4 and a Galaxy A7. The A7 runs Android 6.0.1 (API 23) and the G4 runs Android 5.0.1 (API 21). When I place them side by side outdoors and request location, the G4 gives me 14 dec. digits and the A7 gives 7 digits. Why?

Comment: "The software is intended to assist location of lost handicapped persons, and a few meters difference can mean a wrong turning or entrance" -- meters are at 5 significant digits. 7 significant digits are centimeters. 14 significant digits are best measured in nanometers. The GPS system itself is only accurate to ~1 meter, or 5 significant digits. "I had 14 decimal digits and now I don't" -- please provide a [mcve] demonstrating how exactly you are determining the number of significant digits in your values.

Comment: This is how I get the long. and lat. in displayable format - it worked before and works now, but gives less digits:                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                            
 public void onLocationChanged(final Location loc)    
{
            String myLatitude = "Latitude:  " + loc.getLatitude();
            String myLongitude = "Longitude: " + loc.getLongitude();

}